# Combine mysql views with column IF

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I really need help and enlighment here :-)

I have 3 views:

1st_view "vtabulasi_capaianbantu_fix":

```
    SELECT
    `a`.`tblpok_tahun` AS `tblpok_tahun`,
    `a`.`refsubunit_id` AS `refsubunit_id`,
    `a`.`tblpok_kodesubunit` AS `tblpok_kodesubunit`,
    `a`.`tblpok_kodeunit` AS `tblpok_kodeunit`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu12` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu12`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu11` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu11`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu10` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu10`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu09` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu09`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu08` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu08`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu07` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu07`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu06` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu06`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu05` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu05`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu04` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu04`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu03` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu03`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu02` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu02`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu01` > 0),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu01`,
    0
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
) AS `tblpok_targetkeu`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik12` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik12`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik11` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik11`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik10` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik10`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik09` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik09`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik08` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik08`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik07` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik07`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik06` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik06`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik05` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik05`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik04` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik04`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik03` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik03`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik02` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik02`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik01` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik01`,
    0
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
) AS `tblpok_targetfisik`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu12` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu12`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu11` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu11`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu10` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu10`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu09` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu09`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu08` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu08`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu07` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu07`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu06` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu06`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu05` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu05`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu04` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu04`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu03` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu03`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu02` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu02`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu01` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu01`,
    0
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
) AS `tblpok_realisasikeu`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik12` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik12`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik11` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik11`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik10` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik10`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik09` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik09`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik08` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik08`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik07` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik07`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik06` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik06`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik05` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik05`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik04` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik04`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik03` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik03`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik02` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik02`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik01` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik01`,
    0
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
) AS `tblpok_realisasifisik`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal12` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal12`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal11` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal11`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal10` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal10`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal09` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal09`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal08` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal08`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal07` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal07`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal06` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal06`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal05` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal05`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal04` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal04`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal03` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal03`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal02` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal02`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal01` > 0
    ),
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal01`,
    0
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
) AS `tblpok_realisasikeunominal`,
 `b`.`refsubunit_nama` AS `tblpok_uraian`
FROM
    (
        `vtblpok` `a`
        JOIN `refsubunit` `b` ON (
            (
                `b`.`refsubunit_id` = `a`.`refsubunit_id`
            )
        )
    )
WHERE
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_statusentry` = 'entryTargetRealisasi'
    )
```

2nd_view "vtabulasi_capaianbantu":

```
    SELECT
    `a`.`tblpok_tahun` AS `tblpok_tahun`,
    `a`.`refsubunit_id` AS `refsubunit_id`,
    `a`.`tblpok_kodesubunit` AS `tblpok_kodesubunit`,
    `a`.`tblpok_kodeunit` AS `tblpok_kodeunit`,

IF (
    (`a`.`tblpok_targetkeu` > 100),
    100,
    `a`.`tblpok_targetkeu`
) AS `tblpok_targetkeu`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik` > 100
    ),
    100,
    `a`.`tblpok_targetfisik`
) AS `tblpok_targetfisik`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu` > 100
    ),
    100,
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu`
) AS `tblpok_realisasikeu`,

IF (
    (
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik` > 100
    ),
    100,
    `a`.`tblpok_realisasifisik`
) AS `tblpok_realisasifisik`,
 `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal` AS `tblpok_realisasikeunominal`,
 `a`.`tblpok_uraian` AS `tblpok_uraian`
FROM
    `vtabulasi_capaianbantu_fix` `a`
```

3rd_view "get avg and sum":

```
    SELECT
    `a`.`refsubunit_id` AS `refsubunit_id`,
    `a`.`tblpok_kodesubunit` AS `tblpok_kodesubunit`,
    `a`.`tblpok_kodeunit` AS `tblpok_kodeunit`,
    `a`.`tblpok_uraian` AS `tblpok_namasubunit`,
    avg(`a`.`tblpok_realisasikeu`) AS `tblpok_realisasikeu`,
    sum(
        `a`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal`
    ) AS `tblpok_realisasikeunominal`,
    (
        SELECT
            avg(`b`.`tblpok_realisasikeu`)
        FROM
            `vtabulasi_capaianbantu` `b`
    ) AS `tblpok_realisasikeu_allskpd`,
    (
        SELECT
            sum(`c`.`tblpok_apbdmurni`)
        FROM
            `vtabel_tblpok_level2_by_subunitid` `c`
    ) AS `tblpok_apbdmurni_allskpd`,
    (
        SELECT
            sum(`c`.`tblpok_apbdperubahan`)
        FROM
            `vtabel_tblpok_level2_by_subunitid` `c`
    ) AS `tblpok_apbdperubahan_allskpd`,
    (
        SELECT
            sum(
                `b`.`tblpok_realisasikeunominal`
            )
        FROM
            `vtabulasi_capaianbantu` `b`
    ) AS `tblpok_realisasikeunominal_allskpd`,
    `c`.`tblpok_apbdmurni` AS `tblpok_apbdmurni`,
    `c`.`tblpok_apbdperubahan` AS `tblpok_apbdperubahan`
FROM
    (
        `vtabulasi_capaianbantu` `a`
        JOIN `vtabel_tblpok_level2_by_subunitid` `c` ON (
            (
                `a`.`refsubunit_id` = `c`.`refsubunit_id`
            )
        )
    )
GROUP BY
    `a`.`refsubunit_id`
```

At present I already used this view which is called from this model:

model:

```
$this->db->select("*");
        $query = $this->db->get('3rd_view');
        return $query->result_array();
```

Everything is ok. All passed good til the MVC->view loops for tables.
And now the problem is:

1. I can't alter the view query "where clause" because I need to query this data year filter (`a`.`tblpok_tahun`) in 1st_view. Any opinion/solution?
2. I can't  control 1st_view IF iteration (12 to 1 field ), because I can not pass php var to 1st view query. (For example if I need to filter the data from month 1 to 4, in my php form, theres already combo box for months, I choose 4). Then I need to restrain the nested IF from 1 to 4 nests only. How do we do it?
3. I'm afraid there is some performance degradation using many combined view with alot of IF process inside. (Loading time 8s)
4. Should I find another querying strategy? Should it be heavily coded in mysql or php side?

Thanks for the responds.

Comment: OMG. I'm about 10 years in webdev, but I've never seen before anything like this. Are You using `views` as queries?

Comment: That's what i want to change.... any solution?

Comment: Use `controllers` to detect what action You need to do with request, call suitable `model` to process data and return processed data to `controller`, then send processed data from `controller` to `view` for draw anything for user. This calls `MVC`

Comment: @George Sazanovich, thanks for reply, i already did that, to be brief, all i ask is mainly involved with model strategy approach... not mvc. I use controller to coordinate all the request. my problem is in the model side.